# Moving from visual studio 2008 to visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Any solution to this:

Assembly 'DomainModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

DomainModel\bin\Debug\DomainModel.dll

I have re-added the reference that points to mvc2, and whatmore is required ? Still this error.

ThankYou!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an assembly binding redirection section to your web.config file:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: That isnt helping me still. The config file already contains the above, since its supposed to be automatically populated when installing visual studio 2010.

Comment: It automatically gets populated when converting from 2008 to 2010, so thats something I do not have to touch.
 
I have even tried re-adding the reference, but still no luck.

Comment: Is `DomainModel` your MVC application or is it a seperate project?

Comment: DomainModel is part of project files in MVC

Comment: do u have multi-project solution? if yes check references for other projects too